# telethon : download photos and AuthKeyError

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Probably a silly question. Certainly it's a problem with my code, but actually I got stuck and even not understand where to search.

I want to get the messages and the photos from a channel using telethon.
No problem with messages I got them. Now, I try to get the photos (if there is any in the message).

All messages stored in a list called messages.

Here is my code to download photos :

```
for i, cur_mes in enumerate(messages) :
    print(i)
    print(cur_mes.date)
    print(cur_mes.message)
    if cur_mes.photo :
        print(cur_mes.photo)
        with client :
            try :
                client.download_media(cur_mes.photo,"./img/"+str(cur_mes.date)+".jpg")
            except FloodWaitError as ee:
                e = str(ee)
                time.sleep(int(re.search(r'\d+', e).group()))
                client.download_media(cur_mes.photo,"./img/"+str(cur_mes.date)+".jpg")
```

This code download the first photo. And then it stops with error :

> telethon.errors.rpcbaseerrors.AuthKeyError: RPCError 406:
>   FILEREF_UPGRADE_NEEDED (caused by GetFileRequest)

I don't understand "AuthKeyError: RPCError 406: FILEREF_UPGRADE_NEEDED".
If I try to catch it (cause it's indicated that RPCErrors could be even on the server side), the code will continue to work, but all the photos (except first) are empties.

**UPDATE:**
As @Lonami supposed in the comments, it was a problem of version. I was so sure to ave the laest that I did not think to check it.

```
pip3 install telethon --upgrade
```

solved the problem.

Comment: You seem to be using an old version of the library. Try upgrading, because it is known that Telegram has broken files in old versions.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much. I did something wrong as I was sure that I use the latest one. But actually, I checked and it was the old 1.4.3. I'll install the new version and I'll we back to confirm if it solved the problem. In any case, thank you very much.

Comment: Ok, it was a version problem. I'm very sorry to be so silly and not check it. Thank you very much @Lonami.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Lonami supposed in the comments, it was a problem of version. I was so sure to ave the latest that I did not think to check it.

```
pip3 install telethon --upgrade
```

solved the problem.